# Java Class Loader not able to read resource

Tags: java

I have a file in structure. projectName/src/config/keyfiles/file and my code is in folder  projectName/src/main/java/customProject/package/filename.java
I am trying to read my file with class loader like.

```
    URL url = CommonUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
```

but every time I am getting url as null. passed filename is ./keyfiles/file.

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: The filename is wrong. Have a look in the JAR file and see where it is, and use that name.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure "where you are" in the directory tree, do the following:

```
URL url = YourMainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".");
        System.out.printf("%s\n", url);
```

Then you will know why you can't get your file